# How to handle alert box that appears while page is loading, using selenium java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a ServiceNow webpage by automatically accepting tasks.

Sequence of events:
1. Right on a record and hit 'Accept Task'
2. An alert box shows up asking for my confirmation, I hit the 'Ok' button.
3. ***The page starts refreshing*** and now a 2nd alert box shows up stating the task has been accepted.

What I have tried:

- I could get past steps 1 and 2 using
  `driver.switchTo().alert.accept()`, but doing same thing on step
  3 throws **org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open**
- Using `thread.sleep()` didn't help
- Using `driver.switchTo().defaultcontent()` didn't help as well
- I can override and close the alert using JavaScript Executor but that's not what I want because I need the alert text as well (https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/27)

  > ````
  > // this does the trick of overriding and closing the 2nd alert box, but I need the alert text as well and hence need a better solution```
  > ````

What I have written:

```java
//handling Alert #1
if(driver.switchTo().alert().getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Are you sure you want to accept this task?"))
    {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); //successfully handled Alert #1
        System.out.println("accepted");
    }

Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

//Handling Alert #2
if(driver.switchTo().alert().getText().endsWith("has been accepted"))
    {
        System.out.println(driver.switchTo().alert().getText());
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); //failed to handle Alert #2
    }
```

Possible cause of the issue:
The 2nd alert box appears when the page is loading.

Hope I have made myself clear this time. Please help how to get the text of the 2nd alert box and close it, because the text decides the logic of the later part.

Comment: Ok let me edit the question to include my attempted code snippets

Answer (score 0):

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.getText();
```

you can use this method

Comment: alert.getText() works fine on the first alert but not on the second. Any operation on the 2nd alert (accept, dismiss, gettext) throws the UnhandledAlertException. That's the issue.

Comment: i think try to create another object for alert and try it again